# how to load main.js only after facebook response status is connected in cocos2d-js

Tags: javascript, facebook, cocos2d-js

I am using cocos2d-js for game development. In a script of `index.html` I want to load `main.js` only when some conditions will be fulfilled.
The sample code is the below

```
<script>
if(user_id == data.id)
{
    // call the main.js
}
</script>
```

I tried the below

```
<script>
 if(user_id == data.id)
  {
   (function(document){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = "external_content";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "main.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
        document.write(external_content);
    }
   }(document));
  }
</script>
```

But it does not work. I can not call the main.js from inside another sript. What can I do ? Please help.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. But maybe you could try to load the tag of gamecanvas in the index.html after you get the response. Or make a custom index.html and load other html with the gamecanvas or something like that.

Comment: @AlexG.G. Before execute the response message program load the `main.js` file and then it can't find `gamecanvas` id, and that's why it gives me an error.